# Kubernetes dashboard not working with Nginx Ingress Controller, error "Client sent http request over HTTPS Server"

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

**BEFORE I BEGIN**: I have seen all the posts related to this before posting my question here but none of the suggested solutions work for me - not even adding thee following annotation helped:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
```

**Issue**:
I am not able to make Kubernetes dashboard work with Nginx Ingress Controller. I always get the error "Client sent http request over HTTPS Server" when visiting the ingress URL.

**Software versions**:

```
helm kubernetes dashboard chart version: 6.0.8
nginx ingress version: 0.16.1 (nginx-stable)
```

**Config files**:
My Ingress object is as follows:

```
    ingress:
     enabled: true
     annotations:
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
     hosts:
     - k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com
     ingressClassName: nginx
     secretName: admin-user
     backend:
       service:
         name: kubernetes-dashboard
       port:
         name: 443
       pathType: ImplementationSpecific
       paths:
       - /
       host: k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com
     tls:
     - hosts:
       - k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com
       secretName: nginx-custom-certificate-secret
```

The Nginx Ingress Controller version is 0.16.1 and it is enabled with enableTLSPassthrough=true.

The resulting configuration generated in Nginx Controller for Kubernetes dashboard is as follows:

```
    upstream kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com-kubernetes-dashboard-443 {
       zone kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com-kubernetes-dashboard-443 256k;
       random two least_conn;
    
    server 10.233.69.180:8443 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s max_conns=0;
    
    }
    
    server {
    
    listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
    
    listen unix:/var/lib/nginx/passthrough-https.sock ssl proxy_protocol;
       set_real_ip_from unix:;
       real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-nginx-custom-certificate-secret;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-nginx-custom-certificate-secret;
    
    server_tokens on;
       server_name k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com;
    
    set $resource_type "ingress";
       set $resource_name "kubernetes-dashboard";
       set $resource_namespace "kubernetes-dashboard";
    
    if ($scheme = http) {
          return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
       }
    
    location / {
          set $service "kubernetes-dashboard";
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
          proxy_read_timeout 60s;
          proxy_send_timeout 60s;
          client_max_body_size 1m;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_buffering on;
    
    proxy_pass http://kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com-kubernetes-dashboard-443;
       }
    }
```

I observed that If I change the above config manually by changing http url to **https** in "**proxy_pass**" (like **https:**//kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard-........-443), my k8s dashboard works fine when I visit https://k8s-dashboard.hpsc.prod.mycompany.com in a browser.

**Deployment steps:**

**nginx ingress controller:**

```
    /usr/local/bin/helm install "nginx-stable" --create-namespace --namespace="nginx-stable" nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --version 0.16.1 -f values.yaml
```

values.yaml file:

```
    controller:
      defaultTLS:
        secret: nginx-stable/nginx-custom-certificate-secret   # created using kubectl create secret with certificate.pem and private.pem files.
        enableTLSPassthrough: true
```

**Kubernetes-dashboard deployment:**

```
    helm repo add kubernetes-dashboard https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/
    
    helm repo update
    
    helm upgrade --install kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard --create-namespace --namespace kubernetes-dashboard --set=app.ingress.enabled=false --version 6.0.8 -f values.yaml
    
    sleep 6
    
    kubectl apply -f dashboard-adminuser.yaml
    kubectl apply -f dashboard-clusterrolebinding.yaml
    kubectl apply -f dashboard-secret.yaml
```

The values.yaml file for kubernetes-dashboard is mentioned above in the post as ingress object file.

The RBAC files like dashboard-adminuser.yaml, dashboard-clusterrolebinding.yaml & dashboard-secret.yaml are for the purpose of giving dashboard admin access to cluster so that it can access everything in cluster - that works fine. Hence, not pasting it here as it is not related to **https** access.

Can someone please help me to fix it?

Comment: Can you please share the documentation you are using for deployment.

Comment: @Srividya Thank you for your reply.  Sorry, I didn't understand what do you mean by "documentation for deployment" - is it deployment steps/commands? If so, I have just modified the post adding the deployment steps for nginx as well as kubernetes dashboard. Please have a look and let me know if you need any more info.